# 2006 Suzuki boulevard s40 carburetor lines

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, gasoline

I don’t know where the hose goes, and I would like a diagram to follow. Then, my bike should start (hopefully). Thanks. I have no idea where they go. I didn’t start the work, I just have to finish it; today hopefully. Thanks.

Comment: Have you googled for the fdagram / workshop manual?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The workshop/service manual is the best resource. It will have an entire section on hose and cable routing, to show you exactly where everything goes. 3rd party manuals are available from companies like Haynes and Clymer, but there is more information in the OEM verison.

A cheaper/easier option is to just use a parts fiche. There are plenty available online, such as Partzilla. They will give you a rough idea of what parts go where and in which orientation.

[Suzuki Motorcycle 2006 OEM Parts Diagram for Carburetor - Partzilla.com](https://www.partzilla.com/catalog/suzuki/motorcycle/2006/boulevard-s40-ls650/carburetor)

[image]